# DiscordJS v14 - How to check if bot is already connected to a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have a problem that when I use `interaction.member.guild.voiceStates.cache.get('BOT_ID')` it doesn't update when the bot is already disconnected or being moved.

```
const getVoice = interaction.member.guild.voiceStates.cache;
const botVoiceChannel = getVoice.get('BOT_ID');

if (botVoiceChannel) {
  errEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("I'm already connected to a voice channel")
  return interaction.reply({ embeds: [ errEmbed ] });
}
```

I expect the value of `botVoiceChannel` to change to a new voice channel or null when the bot is being moved or disconnected.

Answer (score -1):

There is an event called `voiceStateUpdate`. Handling it will help you follow the change of voice states and use the updated value of `botVoiceChannel`

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const clientVar = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });

// Event triggered when a user's voice state changes
clientVar.on('voiceStateUpdate', (stateBefore, stateAfter) => {
  if (stateAfter.member.id === 'BOT_ID') {
    const botVoiceChannel = stateAfter.channel;
    // Use the new value of botVoiceChannel here
  }
});

// Any code you like here

clientVar.login('BOT_TOKEN');
```

You problem is likely to be related to not updating `cache` property automatically.